# Inno Script: Skip password if the application is already installed

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create an Inno Setup installer that will require a password from the user if the application has never been installed on the local machine.

I have the script that gets a password, and I have a `Code` section that checks for the existence of the uninstall registry key, but being new to Inno Setup scripting, I'm not sure how to link the two parts together.

Can anyone explain how to forgo the user from entering a password if the app is already installed?

Here is the (test) script...

```pascal
#define myAppID "2B7D6E48-74A8-4070-8BA7-621115D6FD00"

[Setup]
AppId={{{#myAppID}}
Password=123456

[Code]

function checkForPreviousInstall(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#myAppId}_is1') or
     RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#myAppId}_is1') then
  begin
    MsgBox('The application is installed already.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the password page, if the application is installed already.

Use [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents):

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (PageID = wpPassword) and checkForPreviousInstall then Result := True;
end;
```